# Getting a JSONDecode error and I'm not completely understanding as to why it's coming up

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm working with this API and I'm pretty new to both APIs and python, but I keep getting a ***requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)*** when I try to run this code.

This is my code so far:

```
api_base = "https://ergast.com/api/f1/"

@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home_route():

return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/season', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def show_season():

raceYear = request.form.get("season_year")

resp = requests.get(f"{api_base}", params={
    "Race season": raceYear})

results = (resp.json())

return jsonify(results)
```

Now, I've also tried editing the jsonify portion as well, thinking it might be the problem and I changed it to:

```
results = resp.json()

return jsonify(results)
```

But I get the same error message.

Essentially, I'm trying to test the API and make sure that it works and for what I want to do, but also just to see if I understand the process. The end goal is to have the ability to use the API and search with it to find the results I want from a form that I'd submit. In this case, I'm looking for the schedule of the races for a season. So I have the "raceYear" set up on an HTML form where I'd enter "2021" and I would find the results of the schedule for that season.

Any insight or guidance in the right direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Try to print out the response.text and see if it's a json. Probably isn't.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All API queries require a GET request using a URL of the form:
>
> `http[s]://ergast.com/api/<series>/<season>/<round>/...`
>
> where:
>
> `<series>`    should be set to "f1" `<season>`    is a 4 digit integer
> `<round>` is a 1 or 2 digit integer For queries concerning a whole
> season, or final standings, the round element may be omitted. For
> example:
>
> `http://ergast.com/api/f1/2008/...`

http://ergast.com/mrd/

so...

```
resp = requests.get(f"{api_base}{raceYear}")
```

And as it is a get request you can just go to the API endpoint and see what it looks like:

[image]
https://ergast.com/api/f1/2020

So you are going to have to use something like `beautiful soup` to parse the table.

Comment: This actually led me to the answer and I was finally able to figure it out, so thanks so much for just simply answering it and giving me enough to lead to the right direction.  Much appreciated!